# Exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am getting `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` Exception in Following Function

```
public int GetTime()
{
    string time = "17-07-2015 01:11:25"
    time.Replace('-', '/');

    DateTime oldDate = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
    // Difference in days, hours, and minutes.
    DateTime newDate =Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

    TimeSpan ts = oldDate - newDate;
    // Difference in days.
    int differenceInhours = ts.Hours;
    differenceInhours = differenceInhours * 60;
    int differenceInMinutes = ts.Minutes + 1;
    int BalanceTime = differenceInhours + differenceInMinutes;

    return BalanceTime;
}
```

`17-07-2015 01:11:25`  this date is stored in Database

Comment: What is this: `DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));`? Why do you convert a datetime to string and then back to datetime?

Comment: `DateTime newDate  = DateTime.Now;` is sufficient. No need for `DateTime newDate =Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));`

Comment: Hint: `/` is a special char when it comes to `DateTime` parsing. It is a placeholder for your current culture's date-separator which might be `-` or `.` or  \ or whatever. If you want to parse the datetime you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` with this format: `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: String types are immutable, so the result of your second line (the replacement of - for /) needs to be assigned back into a new variable, or time itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, since you know the format of your datetime:

```
 DateTime oldDate = DateTime.ParseExact(time,"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const string time = "17-07-2015 01:11:25";
DateTime oldDate;
time.TryParseDateOrTime(DateTimeRoutines.DateTimeFormat.USA_DATE, out oldDate);
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = oldDate - newDate;
```

But you need to add following class into your project i-e
`DateTimeRoutines.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
/// <summary>
/// Miscellaneous and parsing methods for DateTime
/// </summary>
public static class DateTimeRoutines
{
    #region miscellaneous methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Amount of seconds elapsed between 1970-01-01 00:00:00 and the date-time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date_time">date-time</param>
    /// <returns>seconds</returns>
    public static uint GetSecondsSinceUnixEpoch(this DateTime date_time)
    {
        TimeSpan t = date_time - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        int ss = (int)t.TotalSeconds;
        if (ss < 0)
            return 0;
        return (uint)ss;
    }

    #endregion

    #region parsing definitions

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines a substring where date-time was found and result of conversion
    /// </summary>
    public class ParsedDateTime
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Index of first char of a date substring found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public int IndexOfDate = -1;
        /// <summary>
        /// Length a date substring found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public int LengthOfDate = -1;
        /// <summary>
        /// Index of first char of a time substring found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public int IndexOfTime = -1;
        /// <summary>
        /// Length of a time substring found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public int LengthOfTime = -1;
        /// <summary>
        /// DateTime found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public DateTime DateTime;
        /// <summary>
        /// True if a date was found within the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public bool IsDateFound;
        /// <summary>
        /// True if a time was found within the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public bool IsTimeFound;
        /// <summary>
        /// UTC offset if it was found within the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public TimeSpan UtcOffset;
        /// <summary>
        /// True if UTC offset was found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public bool IsUtcOffsetFound;
        /// <summary>
        /// Utc gotten from DateTime if IsUtcOffsetFound is True
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime UtcDateTime;

        public ParsedDateTime(int index_of_date, int length_of_date, int index_of_time, int length_of_time, DateTime date_time)
        {
            IndexOfDate = index_of_date;
            LengthOfDate = length_of_date;
            IndexOfTime = index_of_time;
            LengthOfTime = length_of_time;
            DateTime = date_time;
            IsDateFound = index_of_date > -1;
            IsTimeFound = index_of_time > -1;
            UtcOffset = new TimeSpan(25, 0, 0);
            IsUtcOffsetFound = false;
            UtcDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
        }

        public ParsedDateTime(int index_of_date, int length_of_date, int index_of_time, int length_of_time, DateTime date_time, TimeSpan utc_offset)
        {
            IndexOfDate = index_of_date;
            LengthOfDate = length_of_date;
            IndexOfTime = index_of_time;
            LengthOfTime = length_of_time;
            DateTime = date_time;
            IsDateFound = index_of_date > -1;
            IsTimeFound = index_of_time > -1;
            UtcOffset = utc_offset;
            IsUtcOffsetFound = Math.Abs(utc_offset.TotalHours) < 12;
            if (!IsUtcOffsetFound)
                UtcDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            else
            {
                if (index_of_date < 0)//to avoid negative date exception when date is undefined
                {
                    TimeSpan ts = date_time.TimeOfDay + utc_offset;
                    if (ts < new TimeSpan(0))
                        UtcDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 2) + ts;
                    else
                        UtcDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1) + ts;
                }
                else
                    UtcDateTime = date_time + utc_offset;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date that is accepted in the following cases:
    /// - no date was parsed by TryParseDateOrTime();
    /// - no year was found by TryParseDate();
    /// It is ignored if DefaultDateIsNow = true was set after DefaultDate 
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime DefaultDate
    {
        set
        {
            _DefaultDate = value;
            DefaultDateIsNow = false;
        }
        get
        {
            if (DefaultDateIsNow)
                return DateTime.Now;
            else
                return _DefaultDate;
        }
    }
    static DateTime _DefaultDate = DateTime.Now;

    /// <summary>
    /// If true then DefaultDate property is ignored and DefaultDate is always DateTime.Now
    /// </summary>
    public static bool DefaultDateIsNow = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines default date-time format.
    /// </summary>
    public enum DateTimeFormat
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// month number goes before day number
        /// </summary>
        USA_DATE,
        /// <summary>
        /// day number goes before month number
        /// </summary>
        UK_DATE,
        ///// <summary>
        ///// time is specifed through AM or PM
        ///// </summary>
        //USA_TIME,
    }

    #endregion

    #region parsing derived methods for DateTime output

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date and time within the passed string and return it as DateTime structure. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date and/or time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="date_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if both date and time were found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDateTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out DateTime date_time)
    {
        ParsedDateTime parsed_date_time;
        if (!TryParseDateTime(str, default_format, out parsed_date_time))
        {
            date_time = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            return false;
        }
        date_time = parsed_date_time.DateTime;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date and/or time within the passed string and return it as DateTime structure. 
    /// If only date was found, time in the returned DateTime is always 0:0:0.
    /// If only time was found, date in the returned DateTime is DefaultDate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date and(or) time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="date_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if date and/or time was found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDateOrTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out DateTime date_time)
    {
        ParsedDateTime parsed_date_time;
        if (!TryParseDateOrTime(str, default_format, out parsed_date_time))
        {
            date_time = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            return false;
        }
        date_time = parsed_date_time.DateTime;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find time within the passed string and return it as DateTime structure. 
    /// It recognizes only time while ignoring date, so date in the returned DateTime is always 1/1/1.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="time">parsed time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if time was found, else false</returns>
    public static bool TryParseTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out DateTime time)
    {
        ParsedDateTime parsed_time;
        if (!TryParseTime(str, default_format, out parsed_time, null))
        {
            time = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            return false;
        }
        time = parsed_time.DateTime;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date within the passed string and return it as DateTime structure. 
    /// It recognizes only date while ignoring time, so time in the returned DateTime is always 0:0:0.
    /// If year of the date was not found then it accepts the current year. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="date">parsed date output</param>
    /// <returns>true if date was found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDate(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out DateTime date)
    {
        ParsedDateTime parsed_date;
        if (!TryParseDate(str, default_format, out parsed_date))
        {
            date = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            return false;
        }
        date = parsed_date.DateTime;
        return true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region parsing derived methods for ParsedDateTime output

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date and time within the passed string and return it as ParsedDateTime object. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date-time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_date_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if both date and time were found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDateTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out ParsedDateTime parsed_date_time)
    {
        if (DateTimeRoutines.TryParseDateOrTime(str, default_format, out parsed_date_time)
            && parsed_date_time.IsDateFound
            && parsed_date_time.IsTimeFound
            )
            return true;

        parsed_date_time = null;
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find time within the passed string and return it as ParsedDateTime object. 
    /// It recognizes only time while ignoring date, so date in the returned ParsedDateTime is always 1/1/1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date-time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if time was found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out ParsedDateTime parsed_time)
    {
        return TryParseTime(str, default_format, out parsed_time, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date and/or time within the passed string and return it as ParsedDateTime object. 
    /// If only date was found, time in the returned ParsedDateTime is always 0:0:0.
    /// If only time was found, date in the returned ParsedDateTime is DefaultDate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date-time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_date_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if date or time was found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDateOrTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out ParsedDateTime parsed_date_time)
    {
        parsed_date_time = null;

        ParsedDateTime parsed_date;
        ParsedDateTime parsed_time;
        if (!TryParseDate(str, default_format, out parsed_date))
        {
            if (!TryParseTime(str, default_format, out parsed_time, null))
                return false;

            DateTime date_time = new DateTime(DefaultDate.Year, DefaultDate.Month, DefaultDate.Day, parsed_time.DateTime.Hour, parsed_time.DateTime.Minute, parsed_time.DateTime.Second);
            parsed_date_time = new ParsedDateTime(-1, -1, parsed_time.IndexOfTime, parsed_time.LengthOfTime, date_time, parsed_time.UtcOffset);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!TryParseTime(str, default_format, out parsed_time, parsed_date))
            {
                DateTime date_time = new DateTime(parsed_date.DateTime.Year, parsed_date.DateTime.Month, parsed_date.DateTime.Day, 0, 0, 0);
                parsed_date_time = new ParsedDateTime(parsed_date.IndexOfDate, parsed_date.LengthOfDate, -1, -1, date_time);
            }
            else
            {
                DateTime date_time = new DateTime(parsed_date.DateTime.Year, parsed_date.DateTime.Month, parsed_date.DateTime.Day, parsed_time.DateTime.Hour, parsed_time.DateTime.Minute, parsed_time.DateTime.Second);
                parsed_date_time = new ParsedDateTime(parsed_date.IndexOfDate, parsed_date.LengthOfDate, parsed_time.IndexOfTime, parsed_time.LengthOfTime, date_time, parsed_time.UtcOffset);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region parsing base methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find time within the passed string (relatively to the passed parsed_date if any) and return it as ParsedDateTime object.
    /// It recognizes only time while ignoring date, so date in the returned ParsedDateTime is always 1/1/1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_date">ParsedDateTime object if the date was found within this string, else NULL</param>
    /// <returns>true if time was found, else false</returns>
    public static bool TryParseTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out ParsedDateTime parsed_time, ParsedDateTime parsed_date)
    {
        parsed_time = null;

        string time_zone_r;
        if (default_format == DateTimeFormat.USA_DATE)
            time_zone_r = @"(?:\s*(?'time_zone'UTC|GMT|CST|EST))?";
        else
            time_zone_r = @"(?:\s*(?'time_zone'UTC|GMT))?";

        Match m;
        if (parsed_date != null && parsed_date.IndexOfDate > -1)
        {//look around the found date
            //look for <date> hh:mm:ss <UTC offset> 
            m = Regex.Match(str.Substring(parsed_date.IndexOfDate + parsed_date.LengthOfDate), @"(?<=^\s*,?\s+|^\s*at\s*|^\s*[T\-]\s*)(?'hour'\d{2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*:\s*(?'second'\d{2})\s+(?'offset_sign'[\+\-])(?'offset_hh'\d{2}):?(?'offset_mm'\d{2})(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            if (!m.Success)
                //look for <date> [h]h:mm[:ss] [PM/AM] [UTC/GMT] 
                m = Regex.Match(str.Substring(parsed_date.IndexOfDate + parsed_date.LengthOfDate), @"(?<=^\s*,?\s+|^\s*at\s*|^\s*[T\-]\s*)(?'hour'\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*(?::\s*(?'second'\d{2}))?(?:\s*(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm))?" + time_zone_r + @"(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            if (!m.Success)
                //look for [h]h:mm:ss [PM/AM] [UTC/GMT] <date>
                m = Regex.Match(str.Substring(0, parsed_date.IndexOfDate), @"(?<=^|[^\d])(?'hour'\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*(?::\s*(?'second'\d{2}))?(?:\s*(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm))?" + time_zone_r + @"(?=$|[\s,]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            if (!m.Success)
                //look for [h]h:mm:ss [PM/AM] [UTC/GMT] within <date>
                m = Regex.Match(str.Substring(parsed_date.IndexOfDate, parsed_date.LengthOfDate), @"(?<=^|[^\d])(?'hour'\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*(?::\s*(?'second'\d{2}))?(?:\s*(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm))?" + time_zone_r + @"(?=$|[\s,]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        }
        else//look anywhere within string
        {
            //look for hh:mm:ss <UTC offset> 
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=^|\s+|\s*T\s*)(?'hour'\d{2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*:\s*(?'second'\d{2})\s+(?'offset_sign'[\+\-])(?'offset_hh'\d{2}):?(?'offset_mm'\d{2})?(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            if (!m.Success)
                //look for [h]h:mm[:ss] [PM/AM] [UTC/GMT]
                m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=^|\s+|\s*T\s*)(?'hour'\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*(?::\s*(?'second'\d{2}))?(?:\s*(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm))?" + time_zone_r + @"(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        }

        if (!m.Success)
            return false;

        //try
        //{
        int hour = int.Parse(m.Groups["hour"].Value);
        if (hour < 0 || hour > 23)
            return false;

        int minute = int.Parse(m.Groups["minute"].Value);
        if (minute < 0 || minute > 59)
            return false;

        int second = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups["second"].Value))
        {
            second = int.Parse(m.Groups["second"].Value);
            if (second < 0 || second > 59)
                return false;
        }

        if (string.Compare(m.Groups["ampm"].Value, "PM", true) == 0 && hour < 12)
            hour += 12;
        else if (string.Compare(m.Groups["ampm"].Value, "AM", true) == 0 && hour == 12)
            hour -= 12;

        DateTime date_time = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, hour, minute, second);

        if (m.Groups["offset_hh"].Success)
        {
            int offset_hh = int.Parse(m.Groups["offset_hh"].Value);
            int offset_mm = 0;
            if (m.Groups["offset_mm"].Success)
                offset_mm = int.Parse(m.Groups["offset_mm"].Value);
            TimeSpan utc_offset = new TimeSpan(offset_hh, offset_mm, 0);
            if (m.Groups["offset_sign"].Value == "-")
                utc_offset = -utc_offset;
            parsed_time = new ParsedDateTime(-1, -1, m.Index, m.Length, date_time, utc_offset);
            return true;
        }

        if (m.Groups["time_zone"].Success)
        {
            TimeSpan utc_offset;
            switch (m.Groups["time_zone"].Value)
            {
                case "UTC":
                case "GMT":
                    utc_offset = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case "CST":
                    utc_offset = new TimeSpan(-6, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case "EST":
                    utc_offset = new TimeSpan(-5, 0, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Time zone: " + m.Groups["time_zone"].Value + " is not defined.");
            }
            parsed_time = new ParsedDateTime(-1, -1, m.Index, m.Length, date_time, utc_offset);
            return true;
        }

        parsed_time = new ParsedDateTime(-1, -1, m.Index, m.Length, date_time);
        //}
        //catch(Exception e)
        //{
        //    return false;
        //}
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date within the passed string and return it as ParsedDateTime object. 
    /// It recognizes only date while ignoring time, so time in the returned ParsedDateTime is always 0:0:0.
    /// If year of the date was not found then it accepts the current year. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_date">parsed date output</param>
    /// <returns>true if date was found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDate(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out ParsedDateTime parsed_date)
    {
        parsed_date = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return false;

        //look for dd/mm/yy
        Match m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=^|[^\d])(?'day'\d{1,2})\s*(?'separator'[\\/\.])+\s*(?'month'\d{1,2})\s*\'separator'+\s*(?'year'\d{2}|\d{4})(?=$|[^\d])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            DateTime date;
            if ((default_format ^ DateTimeFormat.USA_DATE) == DateTimeFormat.USA_DATE)
            {
                if (!convert_to_date(int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value), out date))
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!convert_to_date(int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value), out date))
                    return false;
            }
            parsed_date = new ParsedDateTime(m.Index, m.Length, -1, -1, date);
            return true;
        }

        //look for [yy]yy-mm-dd
        m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=^|[^\d])(?'year'\d{2}|\d{4})\s*(?'separator'[\-])\s*(?'month'\d{1,2})\s*\'separator'+\s*(?'day'\d{1,2})(?=$|[^\d])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            DateTime date;
            if (!convert_to_date(int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value), out date))
                return false;
            parsed_date = new ParsedDateTime(m.Index, m.Length, -1, -1, date);
            return true;
        }

        //look for month dd yyyy
        m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?:^|[^\d\w])(?'month'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[uarychilestmbro]*\s+(?'day'\d{1,2})(?:-?st|-?th|-?rd|-?nd)?\s*,?\s*(?'year'\d{4})(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!m.Success)
            //look for dd month [yy]yy
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?:^|[^\d\w:])(?'day'\d{1,2})(?:-?st\s+|-?th\s+|-?rd\s+|-?nd\s+|-|\s+)(?'month'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[uarychilestmbro]*(?:\s*,?\s*|-)'?(?'year'\d{2}|\d{4})(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!m.Success)
            //look for yyyy month dd
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?:^|[^\d\w])(?'year'\d{4})\s+(?'month'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[uarychilestmbro]*\s+(?'day'\d{1,2})(?:-?st|-?th|-?rd|-?nd)?(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!m.Success)
            //look for month dd hh:mm:ss MDT|UTC yyyy
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?:^|[^\d\w])(?'month'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[uarychilestmbro]*\s+(?'day'\d{1,2})\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s+(?:MDT|UTC)\s+(?'year'\d{4})(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!m.Success)
            //look for  month dd [yyyy]
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?:^|[^\d\w])(?'month'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[uarychilestmbro]*\s+(?'day'\d{1,2})(?:-?st|-?th|-?rd|-?nd)?(?:\s*,?\s*(?'year'\d{4}))?(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            int month = -1;
            int index_of_date = m.Index;
            int length_of_date = m.Length;

            switch (m.Groups["month"].Value)
            {
                case "Jan":
                case "JAN":
                    month = 1;
                    break;
                case "Feb":
                case "FEB":
                    month = 2;
                    break;
                case "Mar":
                case "MAR":
                    month = 3;
                    break;
                case "Apr":
                case "APR":
                    month = 4;
                    break;
                case "May":
                case "MAY":
                    month = 5;
                    break;
                case "Jun":
                case "JUN":
                    month = 6;
                    break;
                case "Jul":
                    month = 7;
                    break;
                case "Aug":
                case "AUG":
                    month = 8;
                    break;
                case "Sep":
                case "SEP":
                    month = 9;
                    break;
                case "Oct":
                case "OCT":
                    month = 10;
                    break;
                case "Nov":
                case "NOV":
                    month = 11;
                    break;
                case "Dec":
                case "DEC":
                    month = 12;
                    break;
            }

            int year;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups["year"].Value))
                year = int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value);
            else
                year = DefaultDate.Year;

            DateTime date;
            if (!convert_to_date(year, month, int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value), out date))
                return false;
            parsed_date = new ParsedDateTime(index_of_date, length_of_date, -1, -1, date);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static bool convert_to_date(int year, int month, int day, out DateTime date)
    {
        if (year >= 100)
        {
            if (year < 1000)
            {
                date = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
            if (year > 30)
                year += 1900;
            else
                year += 2000;

        try
        {
            date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        }
        catch
        {
            date = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Edit:

You can also create extion method `ToDateTime()` as

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this string dateValue, DateTimeRoutines.DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeRoutines.DateTimeFormat.USA_DATE)
    {
        DateTime date;
        dateValue.TryParseDateOrTime(dateFormat, out date);
        return date;
    }
}
```

Now consume it as

```
const string time = "17-07-2015 01:11:25";
DateTime oldDate = time.ToDateTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your:

```
DateTime newDate =Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Try instead:

```
DateTime newDate =Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're passing  `time` represents Date in the `DD/MM/YYYY` format.
By default the `en-US` culture is used by .NET according to which the Date is in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. So, when ToDateTime() method is used it throws error saying

`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.

To avoid this error you can use the below approches

```
DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(time,@"d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);
```

Or

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(time,@"d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```